# ADODB.Connection error '800a0e78' Operation is not allowed when the object is closed

Tags: vb.net, loops, vbscript, ado, recordset

I have class

```
Class dbaccess

Public Sub DBOpenAccess()
    ...
    strConnStr = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DATA SOURCE="
    strConnStr = strConnStr & strDBLoc & ";"
    Set cnnObj = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    cnnObj.Open strConnStr
End Sub
...
Public Function OpenRec()
     Set objRec = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
End Function

    Public Function ExecuteUpdateSQL(strSQLStatement)
         Set objRec = cnnObj.Execute(strSQLStatement)
    End Function
...
    Public Function CloseRec()
         objRec.close
         Set objRec = Nothing
    End Function
End Class
```

When i want execute query from other sub and loop throught recordset

```
Sub transl()
 Set db = New dbaccess
 Call db.DBOpenAccess()
 Call db.OpenRec() 

    Set rst = db.ExecuteUpdateSQL("select * from Translations")
       Do while Not rst.eof
        ...
       rst.movenext
       loop
    rst.close
    Set rst = Nothing
 Call db.CloseRec() 
 Call db.DBClose()
 Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

But I get error  on line `objRec.close`

> ADODB.Connection error '800a0e78'
>
> Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.

What i doing wrong? And how to fix this?

Comment: `ExecuteUpdateSQL` returns nothing? - If it returns `objRec` then `rst` and `objRec` are references the same record set and when you close `rst` explicitly then try to close `objRec` your trying to close the underlying record set twice, hence the error.

Comment: In your code does ExecuteUpdateSQL actually return anything?

Comment: It is original code so i think what it not return anything

Comment: but then `Set rst = db.ExecuteUpdateSQL` would generate other errors....

Comment: It's clearly not possible that the code you posted would raise the error you claim it does. Please make your code sample [minimal, complete, and verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We can't help you when your sample code doesn't allow to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A VBscript function returns its result via an assignment to the function's name:

```
>> Function add(x, y) : add = x + y : End Function
>> WScript.Echo add(4,5)
>>
9
```

So your ExecuteUpdateSQL() should look like this

```
Public Function ExecuteUpdateSQL(strSQLStatement)
     Set ExecuteUpdateSQL = cnnObj.Execute(strSQLStatement)
End Function
```

Mark the `Set` needed for object assignment.

Then you don't need a global (phooey!) variable `objRec`,

```
Set rst = db.ExecuteUpdateSQL("select * from Translations")
```

will set (the one and only) `rst` to the recordset, and no unsuitable interactions (cf. Alex' comment) are possible.

Comment: I has change as you show but still the same error on the same line